# Сreating LL grammar

Tags: parsing

I am trying to create a parser for a given language

> The input language contains conditional statements if ... then ...
> else and if ... then, separated by a symbol ; (semicolon). Condition
> statements contain identifiers, comparison signs <,>, =, hexadecimal
> numbers, sign assignments (:=). Consider the sequence as hexadecimal
> numbers digits and symbols a, b, c, d, e, f starting with a digit (for
> example, 89, 45ac, 0abc )

I ended up with this version of the grammar. Also removed left recursion and ambiguity

```
S -> if E then S S' | I := H
S' -> else S S'' | ; S | $
S'' -> ; S | $
I -> p | q
E -> HE'    
E' -> >HE' | <HE' | =HE'
H -> DH' 
H' -> LH' | DH' | EPS
L -> a | b | c | d | e | f
D -> 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9
```

Will it be possible to create an LL(1) parser according to this grammar. I am confused by the rules with two non-terminals (for example HE')

Comment: LL grammars are a pain to read. If you just want to write a recursive descent parser, you can use EBNF repetition operators (which translate to `while`  or `do ... while` loops). If you just want to write a parser, use an LR(1) parser generator and then you can write the natural left-recursive grammar.  But the answer to your question is yes, it's an LL(1) grammar. (At least, I think it is.)

Comment: @rici, thanks for dispelling my suspicions